# Angular Typeahead needs to capture object

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I am trying to use the Angular Typeahead and the data I am trying to present comes from an $http call. It is an array of objects such as [{"abbrev":"FL", "state":"Florida"}, {"abbrev":"VA", {"state":"Virginia"}]. The html looks like this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="item.state for item in states" typeahead-editable="false" />.
```

The control works in that it retrieves a list from the web service and when the user selects the state it populates the text input correctly and stores the state name in the $scope.selected variable. However what I want stored is the object {"abbrev":"FL", "state":"Florida"} because I want to save the key/value pair in a database. How can I get it to select an object vs just the value?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by actually storing your entire object into `$scope.selected`. It would look something like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="item for item in states" typeahead-editable="false" typeahead-input-formatter="item.state" typeahead-template-url="results.html" />.
```

The changes that need to be made are:

- return the whole item: `typeahead="item for item in states"`
- format the input to show the state: `typeahead-input-formatter="item.state"`
- add template: `typeahead-template-url="results.html"`

Then in your HTML you can define your autocomplete template to show the state name:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="results.html">
    <a>{{match.model.state}}</a>
</script>
```